# How to debug a generated .pptx which the OpenXML SDK claims to be valid but PowerPoint says contains unreadable parts?

Tags: xml, debugging, validation, powerpoint

I am trying to generate pptx files from a script, using the "create a pptx with powerpoint, unzip it, and generate something that looks like that" method, which is occasionally suggested as an alternative to using a library or SDK.

The problem is that I managed to create a .pptx which is valid according to "Open XML SDK 2.0 Productivity Tool for Microsoft Office (build 2.0.5022.0)" (it finds no problems), but when I try to open if with PowerPoint (Office 2007 SP3), I get a scary "PowerPoint detected unreadable content in the file, try recovery yes/no" and a "This file cannot be opened with PowerPoint, do you want to find a converter to open the file on Microsoft Office Online webpage?" dialog box. (I have a non-english Office, so these texts have been translated back to english.) Answering yes and no, respectively, powerpoint appears to open the file fine, and if I save it, I get a slightly different file which then can be opened without the scary dialog boxes, but I would really like to know what is causing the issues (especially since the original file passes the validator just fine).

Any ideas how could I get more verbose error messages from PowerPoint, or narrow down the cause of the issue? (My best guess is to try diffing the generated and the recovered-and-saved-from-powerpoint file, and narrow down the differences, but all the differences appear to me to be non-essential, stuff like the ids used for the references, etc.)

The file itself I have uploaded to https://dl.dropbox.com/u/17196313/piechart_n_titleslide_only.pptx